# how visualize mysql update php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, xml

I am inserting images to mysql database from xml. is there any solution to visualize the process. for example loading percentage or some jquery Progress bar. i tried to change the progress bar value as each product updates but iti is not working.

```
<?php
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gpc;charset=utf8", 'root', '');
$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT id FROM product");
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach ($result as $image){
    $id = $image->id;

    $url = "http://xml.com/not_real_XML_File?&prod_code=$image->id";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
    foreach ($xml -> m as $row){
        $image= $row->image_code;
        if(!empty($image)){
            $sql = $con->prepare("UPDATE product SET image = :image WHERE id = :id");
            $sql->bindValue('id', $id);
            $sql->bindValue('image', $image);
            $sql->execute();
        }
        $base = $row->surati;
        $base = base64_decode($base);
        if (!empty($base)){
            $im = imagecreatefromstring($base);

            if ($im !== false) {
                header('Content-Type: image/png');
                imagepng($im, 'images/'.$row->image_code.'-image.png');
                imagedestroy($im);
            }
            else {
                echo 'An error occurred.';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Something like this: http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/? There are probably few dozens of similar question at SO.

Comment: Some more information would be useful. How are you posting the images to the PHP script? If you are using an AJAX request you could call the script once for each image, wait for it to post back the success message before posting the next one. Then, each time a result comes back you increment the progress bar one more step (being the number returned OK divided by the total number of images to send).

Comment: this is the whole process nothing else is happening. i have link Image Update and when you click this link this code starts to execute

Comment: images are in xml file in base64 format

Comment: Instead of showing image upload progress percentage, you can show Loader image